# Count data from jsonObject

Tags: javascript, json

i have this json object array

```
 [{"Subject":"Maths","status:"Pass"},{"Subject":"Maths","status:"Pass"},
     {"Subject":"Maths","status:"Fail"},{"Subject":"Maths","status:"Fail"},
    {"Subject":"English","status:"Pass"},{"Subject":"English","status:"Fail"}]
```

I want to count number of pass and fail for each subject and store them in object array like

```
[{"Subject":"Maths","Pass":2,"Fail":2},"Subject":"English","Pass":2,"Fail":2}]
```

This data is coming from api also subjects can vary there can be numerous subjects .

Comment: So what's the problem? Getting the JSON from wherever it is stored? Parsing it (it *does* have syntax errors in it)? Looping over an array? Counting? None of this is difficult stuff, but you don't appear to have put any effort into it. Stackoverflow does not exist to write trivial software for people who aren't programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce function and in the accumulator array check if the `Subject` exist. If it does not exist then create an new object and set the value of key `Subject` , `Pass` & `Fail`.
If it exist then update the value of Pass & Fail

```js
let k = [{
    "Subject": "Maths",
    "status": "Pass"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Maths",
    "status": "Pass"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Maths",
    "status": "Fail"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Maths",
    "status": "Fail"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "English",
    "status": "Fail"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "English",
    "status": "Pass"
  }
]

let res = k.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let findSubjectIndex = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.Subject === curr.Subject;
  })
  if (findSubjectIndex === -1) {
    let crtOb = Object.assign({}, {
      Subject: curr.Subject,
      Pass: curr.status === "Pass" ? 1 : 0,
      Fail: curr.status === "Fail" ? 1 : 0
    })
    acc.push(crtOb)

  } else {
    console.table(acc)
    acc[findSubjectIndex].Pass = acc[findSubjectIndex].Pass + (curr.status === "Pass" ? 1 : 0);
    acc[findSubjectIndex].Fail = acc[findSubjectIndex].Fail + (curr.status === "Fail" ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let arr = [{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Pass"},{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Pass"},
     {"Subject":"Maths","status":"Fail"},{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Fail"},
    {"Subject":"English","status":"Pass"},{"Subject":"English","status":"Fail"}];

// Create an obect with key as subject and value as desired object.
let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {Subject, status}) => {
  // if subject exists in object, updating object with count
  if(a[Subject]) a[Subject][status] = (a[Subject][status] || 0) + 1;
  // else adding a new entry for subject
  else a[Subject] = {Subject, [status] : 1};
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

More readable and easy to understand code for newbies like me

```js
var jsonObject  = [{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Pass"},{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Pass"},
     {"Subject":"Maths","status":"Fail"},{"Subject":"Maths","status":"Fail"},
    {"Subject":"English","status":"Pass"},{"Subject":"English","status":"Fail"}];

var passMathCount = 0;
var failMathCount = 0;
var passEnglishCount= 0;
var failEnglishCount = 0;

//Iterate through each object
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
    
    var obj = jsonObject[i];
    //Check combination for respective requirements
    if(obj.status == "Pass" && obj.Subject == "Maths")
      passMathCount++;
    else if(obj.status == "Fail" && obj.Subject == "Maths")
      failMathCount++;
    else if(obj.status == "Pass" && obj.Subject == "English")
      passEnglishCount++;
    else
      failEnglishCount++;
}

//Build json object array
var jsonInstance = [{"Subject": "Maths", "pass": passMathCount, "fail":failMathCount},
                    {"Subject": "English", "pass": passEnglishCount, "fail":failEnglishCount}];
                    
console.log(jsonInstance);
```